# Jquery file upload plugin: Where I should use Upload multiple resolutions of one image code?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, resize

There is a solution for save multiple copy of a image with different resolutions [at this wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options).
But I don't know how and in which file i have to use it.
please help me on this.

```
$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.processActions.duplicateImage = function (data, options) {
    if (data.canvas) {
        data.files.push(data.files[data.index]);
    }
    return data;
};
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    processQueue: [
        {
            action: 'loadImage',
            fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
            maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
        },
        {
            action: 'resizeImage',
            maxWidth: 1920,
            maxHeight: 1200
        },
        {action: 'saveImage'},
        {action: 'duplicateImage'},
        {
            action: 'resizeImage',
            maxWidth: 1280,
            maxHeight: 1024
        },
        {action: 'saveImage'},
        {action: 'duplicateImage'},
        {
            action: 'resizeImage',
            maxWidth: 1024,
            maxHeight: 768
        },
        {action: 'saveImage'}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**upload.class.php**

```
    function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true) {

    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',

       /*.
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .*/,

         /************************************************************************/
         /************************************************************************/
         // find: 'image_versions' and examine the tags (thumbnail,medium)
         /************************************************************************/
         /************************************************************************/

        'image_versions' => array(
            // Uncomment the following to create medium sized images:

            'medium' => array(
                'max_width' => 460,
                'max_height' => 460,
                'min_width' => 140,
                'min_height' => 140,
                'jpeg_quality' => 85
            ),

            'thumbnail' => array(
                'max_width' => 230,
                'max_height' => 230,
                'min_width' => 140,
                'min_height' => 140,
                'jpeg_quality' => 85
            )
        )
    );
```

Image version file path: **".../files/medium/a.jpg"**, **".../files/thumbnail/a.jpg"**, **".../files/a.jpg"**

Comment: Thank you very much it solve my problem.Is this resizing way on client side or server side?

Comment: @RaminSarmadi Server side since it's in php. Is there a way how to rename these resized images?